# Increment and decrement variable until statement is true

Tags: javascript

So I have a variable that ranges in value and there is no way to determine the exact number, only a number close to it (about 50 above or below unknown number). So let's say the correct number is 910 (once again, this number varies to being greater than or less than the already determined number) and I calculate 900. How would I write a function that tries 900, 899, 901, 898, 902, 897...and so on and so forth until it's equal to the unknown variable?

Comment: You could use an absolute value function, but it wouldn't go in the order you've specified.

Comment: How would you compare your guess with the unknown number?

Comment: better use some binary search algorithm to get better performanace

Comment: @ManMohanVyas You can only use binary search when you have an ordered range and if you want to use binary search you assume that you can compare your guess with the unknown number in which case what's the point of even trying to guess?

Comment: No search will finish unless it has a termination condition. How do you know when the search has found the right number?

Comment: @Patashu In either case if you're trying to search for a number you still need a number to search for. Hence if you already have a number then what's the point of trying to search?

Comment: @AaditMShah The unknown number is actually an integer on a server, of which I don't have access to. The already known number (the one that is about 50 more or less than the unknown) is the number pulled from the server's API. To make a request back to the server to get appropriate data, the unknown must be calculated. My thought to test if the number is equal to the unknown was to keep submitting GET requests until a non null response came back.

Comment: @MichaelGeary See my response above.

Comment: @AustinDizzy Why do you have a server which is behaving like such a b****? Is it some sort of a challenge packet?

Comment: @AaditMShah Eh, well, you could say that. A service has a private algorithm that adds or subtracts a random integer (which I've found to be no more than 50) from a user's public `userId` in order to maintain security and I guess to only allot the service itself from submitting proper POST requests. The number it subtracts or adds from the user's public userId is unique to each user. So basically, the public userId for a user isn't the user's actual userId and only the server knows the user's actual userId. So yeah, there's that.

Comment: @AustinDizzy So you're essentially trying to compromise a web service? Are you a white hat or a black hat?

Comment: OK, so the fact that you're testing against a server resource is critical here and should have been stated right up front. It means that any solution involving a simple loop is invalid, because you need to wait for the server response before moving on to the next guess, so the ajax callback will have to be responsible for moving on to the next number to test.

Comment: Not a fan of giving tips on how to break an API's security.

Comment: @AaditMShah Oh no, this isn't for anything malicious at all. And in all reality, I'm making GET requests simply to get a user's timeline/feed. A POST request for this service requires a valid session ID, like it should. They just protect their real userId values to restrict users to using their mobile apps.

Comment: @AaditMShah the problem is with the given gange let say 50 number can be 850 to 950 ... which are in order hence binary search can be used

Comment: @ManMohanVyas If you're using binary search then you should know what you're searching for, and if you already know what you're searching for then what's the point of searching?

Answer (score 1):

```
var guess = x;
var answer = 910;
var high = guess;
var low = guess;

while (high !== answer && low !== answer) {
    high++;
    low--;
}

if (high === answer) {
    print high;
} else if (low === answer) {
    print low;
} else {
    print "how did you get here?";
}
```

Comment: Any kind of ordinary loop won't work, sorry. The OP just mentioned that the number being searched for can only be determined by hitting a server, so it has to be asynchronous ajax code, with the callback moving on to the next value to test.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie You're right, looks like it's me who has to rethink my logic ; ).

Comment: @MichaelGeary, true, but if the OP's just looking for an algorithm, this does answer the question...

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie - Well, that asynchronous requirement does change the algorithm considerably. See my answer for a working version - there isn't a loop anywhere in it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the test for the "unknown" number is actually a server call, you can't do this with a simple loop. Instead you need to deal with everything asynchronously.

Here's an example:

```js
// Starting with guess, test that value and nearby integers up through
// guess+maxDelta and down through guess-maxDelta.
// Each number is tested by calling testMagicNumber(). This function
// can make an Ajax call or other asynchronous action, and then it
// should call the callback passed to it with true or false.
// When a match is found, call the callback function with that value.
// If no match is found call the callback function with false.
function findMagicNumber( guess, maxDelta, callback ) {
    var delta = 0, sign = +1;
    nextNumber();
    function nextNumber() {
        var value = guess + sign*delta;
        //console.log( 'Testing', value );
        testMagicNumber( value, function( match ) {
            if( match ) {
                callback( value );
            }
            else {
                if( sign > 0)
                    ++delta;
                sign = -sign;
                if( delta <= maxDelta )
                    nextNumber();
                else
                    callback( false );
            }
        });
    }
}

// Test version of a magic number matcher, using a hard coded value
function testMagicNumber( value, callback ) {
    callback( value == magic );
}

// Untested example of a function to test a magic number
// with a server request. isMagic(result) is whatever test
// you need to make on the result to get a boolean value
// for the callback.
function testMagicNumberAjax( value, callback ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test',
        data: { value: value },
        error: function() {
            callback( false );
        },
        success: function( result ) {
            callback( isMagic(result) );
        }
    });
}

for( var magic = 45;  magic <= 55;  ++magic ) {
    console.log( 'Magic number is', magic );
    findMagicNumber( 50, 3, function( result ) {
        console.log( 'Matched', result );
    });
}
```

This takes a guess of 50 and a maximum delta up and down of 3, and tests magic numbers from 45 through 55.

The result logged is:

```
Magic number is 45
Matched false
Magic number is 46
Matched false
Magic number is 47
Matched 47
Magic number is 48
Matched 48
Magic number is 49
Matched 49
Magic number is 50
Matched 50
Magic number is 51
Matched 51
Magic number is 52
Matched 52
Magic number is 53
Matched 53
Magic number is 54
Matched false
Magic number is 55
Matched false
```

The `testMagicNumber()` function is where you'll make your Ajax call to hit the server. When you get a response back from the call, `testMagicNumber()` should call its `callback` function parameter with `true` or `false` to indicate if the number matched. There's an example (untested) Ajax version above in `testMagicNumberAjax()`.

You can paste the code above into the Chrome console to do a quick test; change the value of `magic` to try different numbers.